# XSLT key in push transformation, better performance?

Tags: xslt

I am using `<xsl:key>` in a push transformation, using it in template patterns, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="key('div', 'MAIN')">
...
</xsl:template>
```

... instead of:

```
<xsl:template match="html:div[upper-case(@id) = 'MAIN']">
...
</xsl:template>
```

However, I don't know if this has any performance benefits, and lately I've been thinking, since this is a push transformation, and the node is visited anyways, is the key really useful ?

Comment: I think that keys are meant for _dynamic_ cross references. About performance: only repetitive usage makes a difference.

Comment: I agree with @Alejandro.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation why using the key function as the match expression of a template can generally be less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the performance difference may be negligible, when comparing the performance of:

```
<xsl:template match="key('div', 'MAIN')">
```

to that of:

```
<xsl:template match="html:div[upper-case(@id) = 'MAIN']">
```

it seems that the latter *is* more efficient in any case where the `key()` function selects a significant number of nodes.

**Explanation**:

1. Matching a `key()` is equivalent to matching the union of the nodes in the node-set returned by the `key()` function. Thus, the XSLT processor has to decide if the current node belongs to that node-set. This can be a rather inefficient operation, especially if the set of nodes selected by the `key()` function is significant.
2. In the second case we have a simple match. Deciding whether the current node is matched by the match expression involves just one node test and verification of a simple condition. This is generally going to be simpler than checking the membership of the current node to a large node-set.

Answer (score 1):

I very rarely see key() used in a match pattern. I think it's very unlikely to give any significant performance benefits, unless perhaps the "use" condition of the key is very complex and the key is used often enough to amortize the cost of building the index. As always with performance questions, it depends on the processor you are using, and the only real way to find out is to measure it.